# Linux Find File with Exact Size

Tags: linux, command-line-interface, files, find

In the Linux command line, how can I find all files exactly 158 kB in size? I was using the following command but it didn't work:

```
find /var/www/ -xdev -type f -size 158k
```

Comment: Are you sure the file you are seeking is exactly 158kB? That command line should work. I tested it with: `dd if=/dev/zero bs=1 count=161792 of=/tmp/test1; dd if=/dev/zero bs=1 count=161793 of=/tmp/test2; find /tmp/ -size 158k`. It found the file /tmp/test1, but not /tmp/test1. (161792=158kB)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Find files of exact size**

```
[me@localhost ~]$ dd if=/dev/zero bs=1024 count=158 of=/dev/shm/158k.txt
158+0 records in
158+0 records out
161792 bytes (162 kB) copied, 0.00120192 s, 135 MB/s

[me@localhost ~]$ find /dev/shm -type f -size 158k
/dev/shm/158k.txt
```

Your file that was not found is not likely 158 KB.  To validate its size, use `/bin/ls -al /path/to/file` and `stat /path/to/file`

Comment: ok I used stat /path/to/file/filename.php and it returned "Size: 33770." It doesn't state the unit, though. How would I find a file exactly 33770 in size?

Comment: `find /path/to/file -type f -size 33770c`  One reference is [here](http://linux.die.net/man/1/find)

Comment: This works perfectly. Thank you so much for the help!